# Как запланировать код в node js с интервалов в 1 секунду?

Tags: node.js, frontend, backend

Всё ломаю голову и думаю как же лучше сделать. Пример:
Пользователь на клиенте покупает бонус, бонус активируется через N времени к примеру.
По окончанию N времени - я хочу реализовать функционал что бы бонус активировался на бэке без лишнего запроса с фронта.

То есть я хочу сделать так что бы по истечению N времени когда пользователь зайдёт снова на сайт - что бы я не сверял время и не узнавал а нужно ли активировать бонус или нет. Я хочу эту задачу отдать бэку - но не знаю как, очень бы хотел узнать ваши мысли, советы, подходы, возможно вы сталкивались когда-то с этим.

Идея у меня есть всего лишь одна - создать отдельную таблицу в бд куда добавлять например - бонус, время активации, ид пользователя и setTimeout на бэке запустить что бы он каждую секунду проверял эту таблицу. Почему каждую секунду ? потому что активировать бонус конечно лучше в точности до секунды.

Comment: Поставь `npm install cron` почитать [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: Лучше такие задания реализовывать в самой бд, а прикладом просто проверять флажки и отдавать их клиенту

Comment: Хоть какие-то комментарии есть, уже радует, про cron я знаю, возможно да лучше за место setTimeout - создать крон. А про флажки и отдать задачу бд, буду гуглить спасибо.